# ViewPager swipe guesture not working when there's a NestedScrollView inside

Tags: android, android-viewpager, scrollview

- I want to implement a viewpager with fragments inside, one of the fragments has the NestedScrollView inside, but when I put the NestedScrollView inside the layout of a fragment and run the project . The app shows as the picture below:
  [image]
- The scroll gesture of NestedScrollView working well with the AppBarLayout, but NestedScrollView prevents the swipe gesture of viewpager. When the NestedScrollView  scrolls down a little,the AppBarLayout collapsed ,the swipe gesture cannot fired, so I cannot move to the next page of viewpager. **This only happens with the NestedScrollView, the RecyclerView works well** .
- ***How can I make the NestedScrollView working well with the fragment?***
- This is the demo I told above: [demo](https://github.com/sitepoint-editors/Design-Demo) ,please change the layout of the fragment inside viewpager with the layout below: 
  [image]
- **lipsum** is the very very long string

Comment: Have you found any solution to this issue? I'm having same behavior.

Comment: @dgngulcan I also stuck in same issue is there any update regarding this